# Clipboard.GetData return null when a List<T> copied in Clipboard (Windows XP)

Tags: c#, list, serialization, clipboard, copy-paste

I used following codes to `Copy/Paste` list of objects in my project:

```
public static void CopyToClipboard(object obj)
{
    DataFormats.Format format = DataFormats.GetFormat(obj.GetType().FullName);

    IDataObject dataObj = new DataObject();
    dataObj.SetData(format.Name, false, obj);
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj, true);
}
public static object GetFromClipboard(Type T)
{
    object doc = null;
    IDataObject dataObj = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
    string format = T.FullName;
    if (dataObj.GetDataPresent(format))
    {
       doc = dataObj.GetData(format);  //<--- this line return null
    }
    else
    {
       throw new Exception("Data with this format not found!");
    }
    return doc;
}
```

It works fine in `Windows 7`, but in `Windows XP` when I copy `List<MyClass>` to clipboard and want to `paste` it, the `GetFromClipboard()` returns `null`:

```
[serializable]
public class MyClass
{
   //properties
}

var myClasses = new List<MyClass>();
myClasses = GetInitialValues();
CopyToClipboard(myClasses);
...
var pastedObjects = GetFromClipboard(typeof(List<MyClass>));
```

How can I fix this problem?